# LivePersona control doesn't work

Tags: javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I did everything according to the *pnp* documentation (https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/LivePersona/#livepersona-control), but the **LivePersona** control does not work for me.
Photo and name is displaying, but when hovering and clicking, the information card is not displayed.

[image: LivePersona items]

```
import { LivePersona } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/LivePersona";

<LivePersona 
    upn={person.email}
    template={
        <>
            <Persona imageUrl={this.state.photo} text={`${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`} 
                secondaryText={person.jobTitle} coinSize={64} />
        </>
    }
    serviceScope={this.context.serviceScope}
/>
```

Tell me what could be wrong?

upn and email are identical.
[image]

**Packages:**

"@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "3.13.0",

"@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "3.11.0"

Comment: Can you make sure that you are passing correct upn? because in some scenario upn and email can be different

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela, yes, upn and email are identical. Added screenshot above.

Comment: which version of SPFx you are using?

Comment: I use spfx 1.15.2

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

If i hover the native coin before, the LivePersona works.

Looks like LivePersona did not initialize the control

Config :

- "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "^3.14.0",
- "@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "^3.12.0",
- "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.204.0",
- SPFX : 1.15.2

Comment: This is the question similar to "I am having same issue".